# Compare <V extends Comparable<V>> to Integer

Tags: java, generics, comparable, generic-programming

I am new to generics and want to solve a little Task.

I want to give two Objects of type "V extends Comparable" to the class ComparePredicate and then check in method "isOk" if the int-value "value" of a Tree class is between these two Objects. 
I choosed the compareTo method because Integer and V should be of type comparable but the compiler gives an error. 
I think its just an syntactical problem.

So how do i need to write it correct. Hope you guys can help me. 
Thanks for your answers.

Class ComparePredicate

```
public class ComparePredicate<V extends Comparable<V>> implements TreePredicate<V> {

    V minEle;
    V maxEle;

    public ComparePredicate(V minEle, V maxEle) {
        this.minEle = minEle;
        this.maxEle = maxEle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOk(Tree<V> tree) {

        return minEle.compareTo(Integer.valueOf(tree.getValue())) > 0 &&
                maxEle.compareTo(Integer.valueOf(tree.getValue())) < 1;
        //COMPILER ERROR: "The method compareTo(V) in the type Comparable<V> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)"

        return false;
    }

}
```

Class Tree

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private int value;
    private final Tree<T> left;
    private final Tree<T> right;

    public Tree(int v, Tree<T> l, Tree<T> r) {
        this.value = v;
        this.left = l;
        this.right = r;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public Tree<T> getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }

    public Tree<T> getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a `V` is comparable to an `Integer`?

Comment: you can check if your V (minEle,maxEle) is a Integer or maybe better a Number (use instance of) and then cast and compare...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because Integer Implements Comparable and V also. So i thought they could be compared

Comment: `V` is comparable to `V`. `Integer` is comparable to `Integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Tree class

```
static class Tree<T> {
    private T value;
    private final Tree<T> left;
    private final Tree<T> right;

    public Tree(T v, Tree<T> l, Tree<T> r) {
        this.value = v;
        this.left = l;
        this.right = r;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    // getters ...

}
```

And also change `isOk()`

```
    @Override
    public boolean isOk(Tree<V> tree) {
        return minEle.compareTo(tree.getValue()) <= 0 &&
                maxEle.compareTo(tree.getValue()) >= 0;
    }
```